# How to change datetime format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this :

```
var createdDate = '2013-01-21 01:23:44';
createdDate = new Date(createdDate);
date = createdDate.toLocaleDateString();
time = createdDate.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');
console.log(date+' '+time);
```

The result : 1/21/2013 1:23 AM

I want the result : 2013-01-21 1:23 AM

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Does this not help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: I'd suggest using a library for this, such as [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), as date formatting in JS is a huge pain. You have to write far too much code to do it.

Comment: You can also use a [date formating library](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/), for example `createdDate.format.format('Y-m-d g:i A')` will output `"2016-07-13 5:14 PM"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are, of course, vanilla solutions but working with date/time in JS is generally a pain. If you're going to be working with date/time in any serious capacity I would highly recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)'s format method for its robustness and flexibility, and it should be able to do what you want.

Examples from the docs:

```
moment().format(); // "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" (ISO 8601)
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"
moment().format("ddd, hA");                       // "Sun, 3PM"
moment('gibberish').format('YYYY MM DD');         // "Invalid date"
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using moment for a while now and didn't know it was capable of this. A small add: you can load the time string directly into the call like `moment(time_string).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm")`

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the `Number` class to allow for zero padding (to display single-digit days and months with zeroes in the front):

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
  var s = String(this);
  while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
  return s;
}
```

The `pad` function takes an optional `size` parameter which dictates the total length of the number string with the default value of `2`.

You could then update your existing code to split the date into three components (using the `pad` function when printing the result):

```
var createdDate = new Date('2013-01-21 01:23:44');
var date = createdDate.toLocaleDateString();

var day = createdDate.getDate();
var month = createdDate.getMonth() + 1; //months are zero based
var year = createdDate.getFullYear();

var time = createdDate.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');

console.log(year + '-' + month.pad() + '-' + day.pad() + ' ' + time);
```

If you are looking for more elegant or less verbose solutions, you will need to use external libraries.