# How to convert datetime "2020-12-14 16:07:09" to "9 Jan 2020 " in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

as the title described that I want to convert DateTime "2020-12-14 16:07:09" to "9 Jan 2020 " in javascript? is there any easy way of doing it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: time warp with javascript? what have you tried?

Comment: Why would `2020-12-14` be converted to `"9 Jan 2020"`? What's the logic

Comment: @NinaScholz A jump to the left and then a step to the right.

Comment: This question in answered in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38356900/10998398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my previous work i also want this type of, so i created it.
i don't know the way to convert but i can tell you how to create.

let guess we want  a date 23 January 2019,

It’s simple to create 23 and 2019 for  23 January 2019. We can use getFullYear and getDate to get them.

```
    const d = new Date(2019, 0, 23)
const year = d.getFullYear() // 2019
const date = d.getDate() // 23
```

It’s harder to get and January.

To get January, you need to create an object that maps the value of all twelve months to their respective names.

Since Month is zero-indexed, we can use an array instead of an object. It produces the same results.

```
  const months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
]
```

To get January, you need to:

Use getMonth to get the zero-indexed month from the date.
Get the month name from months

```
    const monthIndex = d.getMonth()
const monthName = months[monthIndex]
console.log(monthName) // January
```

Then, you combine all the variables you created to get the formatted string.

```
    const formatted = `${date} ${monthName} ${year}`
console.log(formatted) // 23 January 2019
```

That's it!

If you want like jan,feb,etc...
you can change the values in array as per your requirement.